# Images inside css files are not displayed in Symfony 3

Tags: css, assetic, symfony

I am using Assetic in order to generate and display css, images, js.

```
{% block stylesheets %}
{% stylesheets 'bundles/website/css/*' filter='cssrewrite' %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
{% endblock %}
```

This block is adding in the document -head- the following lines:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/07157ce_part_1_doctor_1.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/07157ce_part_1_jquery.fancybox_2.css" />
```

Which is correct.

Inside the second css file I have:

```
.fancybox-overlay {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
overflow: hidden;
display: none;
z-index: 8010;
background: url('../../bundles/website/images/fancybox_overlay.png');
}
```

Which should be correct, BUT fancybox_overlay.png it's not displayed. It doesn't even exist on the path [DOMAIN]/bundles/website/images/fancybox_overlay.png

But there has been generate the file: /web/images/b35fe69_fancybox_overlay_1.png

I tried to use the image inside an image tag and works fine

```
{% image '@WebsiteBundle/Resources/public/images/fancybox_overlay.png' %}
    <img src="{{ asset_url }}" alt="Example" />
{% endimage %}
```

In order to generate the css file I used the following commands:

```
bin/console assets:install web --symlink
bin/console cache:clear
bin/console assetic:dump --env=dev
```

I don't understand why the background-image inside the css is not displayed.

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation and Symfony3's [best practices](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/web-assets.html):

> **Best Practice** Store your assets in the `web/` directory.

Follow this recommendation, edit your paths accordingly and you should be good to go.